# grep between two lines with specified string

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have this simple plat file (file.txt)

```
a43
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
test1
def
ijk
xyz
test2
kfo
```

I need all lines between test1 and test2 in two forms, the firte one create two new files like

**newfile1.txt  :**

```
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
```

**newfile2.txt**

```
test1
def
ijk
xyz
test2
```

and the second form create only one new file like :

**newfile.txt**

```
test1abccvbbnmtest2
test1defijkxyztest2
```

Do you have any propositions?

***EDIT***

For the second form. I used this

sed -n '/test1/,/test2/p'  file.txt > newfile.txt

But it give me a result like

```
test1abccvbbnmtest2test1defijkxyztest2
```

I need a return line like :

```
test1abccvbbnmtest2
test1defijkxyztest2
```

Comment: yes, I propose you to do some research beforehand : )

Comment: @fedorqui very politely put!

Comment: @fedorqui I edit my question, please can you take a look

Comment: @anubhava sorry I did a mistake, newfile.txt like :
test1abccvbbnmtest2test1defijkxyztest2
I update my question, please take a look again

Comment: `awk`, `csplit`, `python`, `perl`, ... all reasonable suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v fn="newfile.txt" '/test1/ {
   f="newfile" ++n ".txt";
   s=1
} s {
    print > f;
    printf "%s", $0 > fn
} /test2/ {
    close(f);
    print "" > fn;
    s=0
} END {
   close(fn)
}' file
```

Comment: first thank you so  much for your answer .Your first one is working well with me , the second too but I have many of newfile I have n newfile.txt how can I resolve this small issue

Comment: yes the are be named like newfile1.txt  newfile2.txt  newfile3.txt .....newfileN.txt

Comment: For only few open files you don't need explicit `close(f)`.

Comment: @anubhava this is working well, it's a good solution for the second form , please can you give me a solution for a first case please

Comment: That means you haven't tested it yet. This awk command solves both tasks in single command.

Comment: I tested it. But I didn't noticed that is resolved the first form. please give me one moment to check this

Answer (score 0):

Perl, like sed and other languages, has the ability to select ranges of lines from a file, so it's a good fit for what you're trying to do.

This solution ended up being a lot more complicated than I thought it would be. I see no good reason to use it over @anubhava's awk solution. But I wrote it, so here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant {
  RANGE_START => qr/\Atest1\z/,
  RANGE_END => qr/\Atest2\z/,
  SUMMARY_FILE => 'newfile.txt',
  GROUP_FILE => 'newfile%d.txt'
};

my $n = 1; # starting number of group file
my @wg; # storage for "working group" of lines

# Open summary file to write to.
open(my $sfh, '>', SUMMARY_FILE) or die $!;

while (my $line = <>) {
  chomp $line;

  # If the line is within the range, add it to our working group.
  push @wg, $line if $line =~ RANGE_START .. $line =~ RANGE_END;

  if ($line =~ RANGE_END) {
    # We are at the end of a group, so summarize it and write it out.

    unless (@wg > 2) {
      # Discard any partial or empty groups.
      @wg = ();
      next;
    }

    # Write a line to the summary file.
    $sfh->say(join '', @wg);

    # Write out all lines to the group file.
    my $group_file = sprintf(GROUP_FILE, $n);
    open(my $gfh, '>', $group_file) or die $!;
    $gfh->say(join "\n", @wg);
    close($gfh);

    printf STDERR "WROTE %s with %d lines\n", $group_file, scalar @wg;

    # Get ready for the next group.
    $n++;
    @wg = ();
  }
}

close($sfh);

printf STDERR "WROTE %s with %d groups\n", SUMMARY_FILE, $n - 1;
```

To use it, write the above lines into a file named e.g. `ranges.pl`, and make it executable with `chmod +x ranges.pl`. Then:

```
$ ./ranges.pl plat.txt 
WROTE newfile1.txt with 5 lines
WROTE newfile2.txt with 5 lines
WROTE newfile.txt with 2 groups
$ cat newfile1.txt 
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
$ cat newfile.txt
test1abccvbbnmtest2
test1defijkxyztest2
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second for you can add a new line after "test2" adding `\n`

```
sed -n '/test1/,/test2/p' file.txt  | sed  -e 's/test2/test2\n/g' > newfile.txt
```

`sed` is not useful to create multiple files so for the first one you should find another solution.

Comment: What do you think of awk, it's useful for multiple files ?